# Can I right-click a folder in Windows 7 and choose "Open with Sublime Text"?

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2

In Windows 7, I can do this at the command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" samplefolder
```

This launches a Sublime Text window, with the contents of `samplefolder` loaded in Sublime's sidebar.

While this works as needed, it's inconvenient to open a command prompt every single time. Is there any way I can add this behavior to Windows Explorer's right-click menu? I'd like to be able to right-click a folder and "Open with Sublime" just like I can right-click a folder and "Scan for viruses".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is my .reg file for Vim, but it's quite clear, just replace Vim related string with Sublime's. Then save as .reg file and double click to import.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vim]
@="&Vim here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vim\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vim]
@="&Vim here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vim\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe\" \"%V\""
```

There are two folder context menu, one is direct right click on folder, that's the first two lines, and another one is **in** folder empty area right click, that's the last two lines. I don't know what did the last `%V` mean, and haven't found anything related, it just works.

**Edit:**

For default installation of Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7, here is the full code.
Save as `whatever.reg` and double-click.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\sublime]
@="Open Folder as &Sublime Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""


; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\sublime]
@="Open Folder as &Sublime Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Comment: I added the key (with %1 at the end) by hand to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ and it worked. Thanks! Skipping the second line (with %V at the end) for the time being.

Comment: Note: if you're using Sublime Text 2, make sure you replace `Sublime Text` with `Sublime Text 2`

Comment: How do they do those little icons?

Comment: +1 This worked great.  However, I added the ability to edit single files.  I put all of this in a repo over here:   https://github.com/cbmeeks/sublime-text-2-context-menu-windows

Comment: I have created a github repo too before seeing cbmeeks comment :( well here is mine [OpenWithSublime](https://github.com/melenaos/OpenWithSublime)

Answer (score 1):

I found a [super solution](https://gist.github.com/jcppkkk/8330314) posted on github gist by [Jethro Yu](https://gist.github.com/jcppkkk)

**Installation instructions:**

- Download the [`OpenWithSublimeTextAsAdmin.bat`](https://gist.github.com/jcppkkk/8330314#file-openwithsublimetextasadmin-bat) file in that gist.
- Copy it into your Sublime Edit installation folder (typically C:\Program files\Sublime Text 3 or similar)
- Run it.

**Features:**

- Super easy installation.
- Open files with Sublime Text
- Open files with elevated privileges with Sublime Text. This is particularly handy when you want to edit i.e. system files.
- Open folders with Sublime Text

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do

I install [Notepad Replacer](http://www.binaryfortress.com/notepadreplacer/) and point that to my `sublime_text.exe` (or any other text editor).

I then add the 'Open with Notepad' Registry setting (copy and paste the following into a `.reg` file and double click to apply it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad\command]
@="notepad.exe %1"
```

What Notepad Replacer does is replaces any command (system wide) to open `notepad.exe` to open the text editor that you specified in the install (in this case `sublime_text.exe`).

If you uninstall Notepad Replacer or re-install it pointing to a different text editor, your 'Open with Notepad' context menu will still work with the new default text editor!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Sublime Text 2" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "\"%~dp0sublime_text.exe\",0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Sublime Text 2\command" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "\"%~dp0sublime_text.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

how to use

new a *.bat file

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just open regedit.exe and browse to:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell

Right-click on "shell" and choose to create a new key, calling it "Open with Sublime Text".

Create a new key below that one called "command".

Double-click on the (Default) value in the right-hand pane and enter in the following:

> [sublime text .exe name] %1

Comment: This only works for opening files. It doesn't work for opening folders.